# With TYPO3 be_layout, how to choose frontend template correctly (performance-wise)?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

In most of my sites, I've been using the following code to decide which template should be applied to the content rendering - based on what the editor has picked in `be_layout`:

```
page.10 = TEMPLATE
page.10 {
    stdWrap.if {
       value = 1
       isInList.data = levelfield:-1,backend_layout_next_level,slide
       isInList.override.data = TSFE:page|backend_layout
    }
    template = FILE
    template.file = fileadmin/templates/main/tmpl/main.html
    ...
}
page.20 = TEMPLATE
page.20 {
    stdWrap.if {
       value = 2
       isInList.data = levelfield:-1,backend_layout_next_level,slide
       isInList.override.data = TSFE:page|backend_layout
    }
    template = FILE
    template.file = fileadmin/templates/main/tmpl/special.html
    ...
}
```

This works perfectly well.

But I had expected that the `if` condition would make sure that unnecessary page objects are not processed at at all. Until I've been looking into some performance issues via the admin panel: I discovered that both (all) child objects of `page.` seem to be rendered - even when the `if` condition doesn't apply.

It looks like it's processed regularly, and then simply not displayed! So the page rendering time explodes when using multiple templates.

[image]

Do I interpret this correctly? 
What is the correct, perf-efficient way to do this?
Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CASE object doesn't "misbehave" like the "if" condition in stdWrap.

Here's the solution that works for me from http://forum.typo3.org/index.php?t=tree&th=207295&goto=723619&#msg_723619: apply the CASE one level upwards:

```
page.10 = CASE
page.10 {
    key.data = levelfield:-1,backend_layout_next_level,slide
    key.override.field = backend_layout
    default = TEMPLATE
    default {
        template = FILE
        template.file = fileadmin/templates/main/tmpl/main.html
        marks {     
                LANG < temp.language
                BASEURL < temp.baseurl
                # ... more marks
        }
    }
    # If BE Layout 1 (Standard page) - corresponds to be_layout uid
    # could be omitted, only for beauty
    1 < .default
    # If BE Layout 2 (Landingpage) - corresponds to be_layout uid
    2 < .default
    2 {
        template.file = fileadmin/templates/main/tmpl/main.html
        marks {
                MAINCONTENT < temp.teaser
                CONTENT_NAV >
                CONTENT_NAV =
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this could/should also be used with a fluid template

From a site that uses 4 different be_layouts, here are the rendering times - before and after the introduction of the CASE:

[image]

Comment: PS I use nc_staticfilecache anyway, but still, this makes a huge difference editors and feusers

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CASE object because the file property is stdWrap enabled:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    typeNum = 0
    bodyTag = <body>

    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        [... skipping some stuff...]
        file.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
        file.stdWrap.cObject {
            key.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
            key.override.field = backend_layout

            default = TEXT
            default.value = fileadmin/Templates/layoutA.html

            2 = TEXT
            2.value = fileadmin/Templates/layoutB.html

        }
    }
}
```