# Typo3 file extensions doubled after upgrade

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

I did an upgrade from Typo3 4.5 LTE to 6.2 LTE, following the instructions found here: [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675796/how-to-upgrade-typo3-4-5-to-6-2)
Now during the process of using the Upgrade wizard the Excepiton #1314516809 occured. 
Then I went to the db using my php-myadmin and corrected the CaseSensitive-Value as recommended here:[wiki.typo3](https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1314516809)
but the error stays. Rereading the code i realized, that the files, which could not be found, had doubled file extensions like 
File /_migrated/RTE/RTEimage.jpeg.jpeg does not exist.
How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.
[Migration of RTE images](https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1319455097#Migrate_all_RTE_magic_images_from_uploads.2FRTEmagicC_.2A_to_fileadmin.2F_migrated.2FRTE.2F)

You must modify the database table sys_file_storage and remove the image entries which cause problems. The images of the migration folder should not remain here.