# typo3 upgrade 4.7 => 6.2 is losing images

Tags: typo3, upgrade, typo3-6.2.x, fal

I've done quit a couple of upgrades from t3 4.X to 6.X but this time I have a persistent problem I cannot not understand. After doing the upgrade (all upgrade wizards ran fine), I can see in the database that the image column of tt_content has the FAL index values in it and not the file names anymore. The references to the FAL tables are ok as well. When I look at CEs like textpic, however, the image tab does not show any images. No images are shown in the FW either.

I could think of trying to fix this in TS but I want to upgrade this install to 8 and think that when the first upgrade needs such a clutch, further updates will be doomed right from the start.

[edit #1]
I'm 100% sure it worked before. But now, whatever I do (update ref index, ...), sys_file_reference stays empty.

---

[edit #2]
I now followed [How to upgrade TYPO3 4.5 to 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675796/how-to-upgrade-typo3-4-5-to-6-2/28675797#28675797) and it worked. Strange thing is that it's not really that different from how I did it all the time. Maybe it just needed me to try it 27 times :)

Answer (score 0):

your problem might depend on individual contentelements. if you have individual definitions the upgrade wizard does not know, these definitions stay unchanged and as a result your 'new' images (sys_file records) are not inserted correctly.

**Individual CEs might need extra care at each upgrade.**

After 6.2 FAL was stable and had no big changes. I would not expect the same amount of work for further upgrades.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This particular website (TV based) is only using standard CEs, though.

Answer (score 0):

In TYPO3 Version 6.2 the `fileadmin`-folder is represented by an automatically created storage record. In this record is a setting to respect case-sensitive filenames.
If this setting is not enabled before the migration of all media-files, then all media-files with upper-case characters are written in the database but not found anymore by the file-system because they are written lower case then.
So if you never find any images on the page after migration I assume all images had one or more upper-case characters in the filename.
If you've only a few images you could change the filename in the database, specifically in the table `sys_file` and the column `identifier`, else it's the best to repeat the whole process and care about the setting in the storage-record `fileadmin` in time.
Storage-records are located on the root-page [uid=0] in the backend, where also backend-users are resided.

Below is a partial screenshot of the database-table `sys_file`:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep this in mind once I get a step further. (see edit above)

Answer (score 0):

My experience was that mysql mode `SQL_STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` was in the middle of the problem. Once changed, `sys_file_reference` begins to fill the records correctly.